# Loading a paragraph of text into a string vector

Tags: c++, vector

When I run this program as is, the text is returned without any spaces. How do I get it to recognize each individual word separately?

```
  int main()

{
    ifstream input1;
    input1.open("Base_text.txt");

    vector<string> base_file;
    vector<int> base_count;


    if (input1.fail())
    {
        cout<<"Input file 1 opening failed."<<endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    make_dictionary(input1, base_file, base_count);


}

void make_dictionary(istream& file, vector<string>& words, vector<int>& count)
{


    string word;
    int i=0;

    while (file>>word)
    {
        words.push_back(word);
        cout<<words[i];
        i++;
    }


    for (i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
    {
        if ((words[i+1]!=words[i]))
            {
                count.push_back(i);

            }
    }


}
```

Current output:

```
Thisissomesimplebasetexttouseforcomparisonwithotherfiles.Youmayuseyourownifyousochoose;yourprogramshouldn'tactuallycare.Forgettinginterestingresults,longerpassagesoftextmaybeuseful.Intheory,afullnovelmightwork,althoughitwilllikelybesomewhatslow.
```

Expected output should have spaces in between each word. I need to be able to sort the words alphabetically after this, so I need to fix more than just the output.

Comment: Consider using istream and ostream iterators, might make your code a lot cleaner (and easier!).

Comment: Side note: replace `vector` with `map<string, int>`, set it `words[word]++` and you get sorted words with count calculated for free.

Comment: Looking back at your previous questions I think you have some unusual misunderstandings. You seem to think that your output some how implies what's happening internally in your code. So that fact that your output doesn't have spaces somehow means you program hasn't recognised the individual words. In your first question you also thought that because you only output one word somehow your program had only read one word. But the code you have always has read and recognised each individual word. Now it up to you to do what you want with those words, sort them, count them, output them etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
cout<<words[i];
```

to this

```
cout << words[i] << ' ';
```

Remember your program does exactly what you tell it to. If you don't tell it to output spaces it won't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a string containing a space when you output the word with `cout`

```
cout << " " << words[i];
```